# Create nested empty Json objects

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I want to create the nested empty Json objects. I tried for one layer using `JSON_Query('[]')`. But how to do for nested objects?

Expected output should be:

```
{
  "Model": [
     {
       "ModelName": "Registration",      
        "Student": [
           {                   
             "Marks": [
                {                          
                   "Notes": [
                     {                                   
                       "Visible": []
                     }
                   ]
                 }
              ]
           }
         ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve a nested json you can use joins. A possible solution is to define table variables and then join them to build the structure you need.
Then you can generate the json output with `for json auto`.

Here is a simple query you can start from:

```
declare @Model   table (ModelName nvarchar(50))
declare @Student table (ModelName nvarchar(50),Student nvarchar(50))
declare @Marks   table (Student nvarchar(50),Mark nvarchar(50))
declare @Notes   table (Mark nvarchar(50))
declare @Visible table (Mark nvarchar(50))

insert into @Model select 'Registration'
 
select *
from
              @model Model 
    left join @Student Student on Model.ModelName= Student.ModelName
    left join @Marks Marks     on Marks.Student  = Student.Student
    left join @Notes Notes     on Notes.Mark     = Marks.Mark
    left join @Visible Visible on Visible.Mark   = Marks.Mark
for json auto, ROOT('Model')
```

Output:

```
{
   "Model":[
      {
         "ModelName":"Registration",
         "Student":[
            {
               "Marks":[
                  {
                     "Notes":[
                        {
                           "Visible":[
                              {

                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```